# Python: Program for sequence logo generation using pyseqlogo

Tags: python, range, sequence, biopython, seq

I'm trying to use this program to plot sequence logos in python using pyseqlogo. The program opens the file input from the user, creates a matrix 4 by seqLength matrix and inputs whatever number of nucleotide happens in a for loop.

I'm getting the error that in the line "if line[i] == "A": " is out of range for some reason.

```
import pyseqlogo
count=0.0
seqLength=0.0

file=input("Input file name: \n")#user input file name 

seqfile= open(file,'r')#opens file 
seqLength= len(seqfile.readline())-1 #Reads line from opened file 
NT_c = [0]*4 #Creates slots for base nucleotide A,C,G,U

for i in range(4):
    NT_c[i] = [0]*seqLength #Uses seqlength to make an "i" length for each NT_C

#Counting nucleotides from file lines 
for line in seqfile: #For loop that will read line by line in file 
    line = line.upper() #Makes all input uppercase
    for i in range(seqLength): #for loop to input data in matrix
        if line[i]== "A":
            NT_c[0][i] =NT_c[0][i]+1 #position I will add one for each A in line 
        elif line[i]=="G":
            NT_c[1][i]=NT_c[1][i]+1 #position 1i adds a 1
        elif line[i]=="C":
            NT_c[2][i]=NT_c[2][i]+1
        elif line[i]=="U":
            NT_c[3][i]=NT_c[3][i]+1
        elif line[i]=="-":
            continue #skips positions with - value
        else:
            print("Error\n") #If none of these, there's a mistake 
    count=count+1
```

Comment: What is your 'i' value? If there is out of range error, it means that you refer to index which is not present in the current list...

Comment: The 'i' value is the letter that is being read from the nucleotide sequence line. This comes from a separate file that is input into the program in the "file=" line. Does that help? @kosist

Comment: Not sure about that. This line of code `for i in range(seqLength` tells that `i` is index (integer value). And `line[i]` means that you refer to `i` element of `line` list (which might be empty though).

Comment: I checked the input files again and I'm not sure why they were blank. Must've deleted them somehow. Thank you! That fixes that issue, but I still don't understand how to input the data into the pyseqlogo.draw_logo.